# How to list hive variables available in a notebook session?

Tags: databricks

In a hive session it is possible to list the variables available with the following:

```bash
0: jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10000>set;
```

How can I list the hive variables from a databricks notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to just run the `SET` SQL command:

```
%sql
SET
```